# Is there no "expose" feature (show all tabs) in iterm2 on Big Sur?

Tags: iterm

The documentation says that <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> should show all tabs, but I am unable to do that.

https://iterm2.com/documentation/2.1/documentation-one-page.html

Under "Expose Tabs"

Comment: Where in the documentation?

Comment: https://iterm2.com/documentation/2.1/documentation-one-page.html under "Expose Tabs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backstory is here: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9433

I removed it because it was very slow and buggy. It was some of the oldest AppKit code I wrote, and it showed. Better alternatives are:

1. Global search — replaces the search feature of expose.
2. Open Quickly — a faster UI to jump to a tab that searches things like current directory, recent commands, etc.